# Is there way for polygon decomposition by thickness?

Tags: image-processing

Here is an example

dots representing coordinates of pixels

[image]

---

*added more representative example*

[image]

---

*added real example*

[image: added real example]

*added main problem*

[image: main problem]

Comment: I see two figures consisting of rectangles, both congruent, one in grayscale and one in colors. What would you like to cluster here?

Comment: gray is an image which is I should to process somehow to get second, colored image

Comment: Ah. It sounds like you actually don't want to *cluster* shapes, but to *cut* them into the smallest possible number of rectangles, correct?

Comment: yeah, split them, and get coordinates of it

Comment: @Oleg Does it fit over there or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clear if it should be on the computer graphics SE or not.

Comment: Yes it should, @PeterFlom

Comment: Use a sweep line algorithm.

Comment: @lightxbulb as far I understood that algorithm more suited for finding if any two line segments intersect or not, so it not helped me much

even if I use Canny, and get contours, I still need a fully classified rectangles with corner points

Comment: It has multiple uses, think of it more as an algorithm design strategy, the segment intersection algo is just one application. For instance in your case you can sweep horizontally, and check the first time `y_start` and `y_end` change, where those are the lower and upper y bounds of your points. In your example it will be `(0,1)`, then you walk along `x` and at the 7th column those change, so you combine the last 6 columns in one rectangle, etc. Note that this works only for 1 rect on over 1 `x` coord, an extension to the general case is trivial though.

Comment: @lightxbulb meh... it's a little bit hard to understand, could you draw a scheme?


I also thinking about np.meshgrid, because my data not so perfect, so I interpolate it first

Comment: Sorry, I will not be making a scheme. I'll try to elaborate though. Let's say you are given the grid of pixels, and the lower and upper leftmost pixels that are black, for instance `(0,0)` and `(0,1)` in your image. You can make a single step along `x` and check whether anything changes - that is check that `(1,0)` and `(1,1)` are black - if they are not, your rectangle ends. You additionally check for `(1,-1)` and `(1,2)` - if any of those are black, then a new rect starts. For your example, the first time any of these checks results in a new rect is at step 7, when the bounds are `(6,0)` and

Comment: `(6,1)`, notably we find that `(6,2)` is not white, and find the new bounds `(6,0)` and `(6,2)`. This keeps going till 6 more steps in, when the check for `(12,3)` being white fails, and the new bounds are `(12,0)` and `(12,7)`.

Comment: data is bidirectional, have a look, I updated OP post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98988/discussion-between-oleg-and-lightxbulb).

Comment: I don't have time to chat, but the idea remains the same  even with your "bidirectional data". You have two points at each end facing each other, and you step through with both at the same time - a dent or protrusion (the distance between the points changing) resulting in a new rect.

Comment: @lightxbulb I added another one image, that shows complexity of my problem - with 3x3 kernel - amount of data is enormous, I just can't predefine all variants (plato, corners, inner  - for all edges + diagonals) Meanwhile variant suggested by you do not provide enough data for further classification (height, width, coordinates)

Comment: No kernels are required. You just need two points on opposite sides of the boundary (inside). Then you just step perpendicular to the line segment formed by the two points and check the cells "in front" of those and diagonally to them. Try thinking it through - the algorithm is not that hard.

Comment: meh.. maybe tomorrow, but now my brain is dead already, sorru ~_~

Comment: Is this still open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write an algorithm where you would iteratively fill lines into rectangles and create a rectangle merging and splitting procedure based on area and thickness. I will use the following image as an example image for the algorithm:

[image: base image wall thickness decomposition]

**Step 1**
Find all the uninterrupted horizontal and vertical lines in the image.

[image: all horizontal uninterrupted lines][image: all vertical uninterrupted lines]

In python you would do something like this:

```
def horizontal_longest_lines(im):
   counts = {}
   on_a_line = False
   line = None
   for row_index, row in enumerate(im):
       for col_index, pixel in enumerate(row):
           coord = (row_index, col_index)
           if not pixel:
               on_a_line = False
               line = None
               continue
           if pixel:
               if not on_a_line:
                   on_a_line = True
                   line = (coord, coord)
                   counts[line] = 1
               else:
                   current = counts[line]
                   del counts[line]
                   line = (line[0], coord)
                   counts[line] = current + 1
   return counts

def vertical_longest_lines(im):
   counts = horizontal_longest_lines(im.transpose())
   new_counts = {}
   for key in counts:
      new_counts[(key[0][::-1], key[1][::-1])] = counts[key]
   return new_counts
```

**Step 2** fill the area around the lines to create rectangles from the lines:

[image: from line to rectangle for wall thickness decomposition algorithm]
[image: from line to rectangle for wall thickness decomposition algorithm]
[image: from line to rectangle for wall thickness decomposition algorithm]
[image: from line to rectangle for wall thickness decomposition algorithm] etc.

For a more efficient algorithm, you could improve this step by trying to merge existing lines into rectangles. But that would probably a bit more complicated to write.

**Step 3** Since some lines will create the same rectangle, these duplicate rectangles need to be removed.

**Step 4** Find overlapping rectangles, give preferences to rectangles that have a bigger area. Cut off the overlapping part from the smaller rectangle.
For these two rectangles:

[image: overlapping rectangles]
[image: overlapping rectangles]

The result would then be:

[image: split rectangles algorithm]

**Step 5** Some edge cases can happen, where the resulting cut-off does not result in a new rectangle. For these cases, split the resulting shape in new rectangles.
For instance in this case:

[image: edge case wall splitting]
[image: edge case wall splittinge]
[image: edge case wall splitting]
[image: edge case wall splitting]

Do note, there are two possibilities here in splitting up the resulting shape. You would need to fine-tune this process.

**Step 6** Merge rectangles that have exactly the same width as the other rectangle's height and are touching each other.

All  the resulting rectangles are now the decomposed walls by thickness:

[image: result wall thickness decomposition algorithm]

Comment: Nice solution mate! but as for me — I needed a 100% robust & 0 maintenance way, so I ended up with plain simple template matching, categorized by wall thickness. But thank you anyway! Hope it would be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to try to abuse clustering algorithms for this. In particular k-means will *not* cut vertically, nor consider rectangles.

What you need to do is a trivial axis-aligned corner detection.it does not get much simpler than that!

You begin on the left, and whenever the location of the topmost pixel changes, a rectangle is complete.

Comment: imagine bw floor plan with different wall thickness, so thickness can vary in different directions